# How to set animator for left to right and inverse for Multiple Screens

Tags: android, animator

I want to make an animation for `ImageView` which runs from left to right on screen and when it reached to 50% of screen, it comes back. My `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="250" >
</objectAnimator>
```

My application ran well on my phone but when it ran on a smaller or bigger phone, it didn't run well.
I want to use `ObjectAnimator` and my application min SDK API is 13. Who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better structure, a dynamic approach is recommended which uses display screen width

First calculate the screen width to measure the half of the screen

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point point=new Point();
    display.getSize(point);
    final int width = point.x; // screen width
    final float halfW = width/2.0f; // half the width or to any value required,global to class
    ObjectAnimator lftToRgt,rgtToLft; // global to class

    // initialize the view in onCreate
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButtontest);

    // set the click listener  
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
               anim();// call to animate
         }
     });
```

Add the below function to your class and enjoy.

```
void anim(){
    // translationX to move object along x axis
    // next values are position value
    lftToRgt = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( imageView,"translationX",0f,halfW )
            .setDuration(700); // to animate left to right
    rgtToLft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( imageView,"translationX",halfW,0f )
            .setDuration(700); // to animate right to left

    AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();//required to set the sequence
    s.play( lftToRgt ).before( rgtToLft ); // manage sequence
    s.start(); // play the animation
}
```

Check out the complete [Code Snippet](https://gist.github.com/Pavneet6293/cb760df224fea66f16e3bb76194aa871)

Comment: Thanks in advance. But I want to use objectAnimator and my application on API 13.

Comment: @KhoaMadridista you should have said it earlier

Comment: @KhoaMadridista here you go buddy